# What is supremum of$f(x,y) =(x^{8/3}y^{11/4}e^{-3xy})$,$x\in[0,\infty),y\in[0,b].$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For which values of $x$ and $y$, we will get the supremum of $f(x,y)  =(x^{8/3}y^{11/4}e^{-3xy})$. Where $x \in [0,\infty), y\in[0,b].$
Actually I have done that  $f_x =(8/3 - 3xy) x^{5/3}y^{11/4}e^{-3xy}=0$ then $xy =8/9$ and $f_y=(11/4 -3xy)x^{8/3}y^{7/4}e^{-3xy}=0$ then $xy=11/12$. Here $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2>0$ that means $f(x,y)$ is either max or min. I have also found that $f_{xx}<0$ and $f_{yy}<0$ for both $xy=8/9$ and $xy=11/12$. But I can't get the result for which values of $x$ and $ y$ we will get the supremum and what is supremum of that function so please do help me.

Comment: You need to worry about the boundary.

Comment: I don't understand about the boundary means please clarify it.

Comment: The line $x=0$, obviously no good. The line $y=0$, ditto. The line $y=b$. This gives a one-variable problem.

Comment: if we take $x\in[0,\infty],y\in[0,1]$ then what happening here

Comment: I am surprised no one has answered. It is very late here. Maybe I can look at your computation tomorrow, check its correctness, deal with the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we cannot have simultaneously $3xy=\frac{8}{3}$ and $3xy=\frac{11}{4}$, so there are no critical points in the interior.   The partials are $0$ where $x=0$ or $y=0$, but $f(x,y)=0$ on the axes. So the only points of interest are the points on the line $y=b$. There we are looking at the one-variable function $g_b(x)$, where
$$g_b(x)=b^{11/4}x^{8/3}e^{-3bx}.$$
This is $0$ at $x=0$, and can be made arbitrarily close to $0$ by taking $x$ large enough. So it takes on a maximum somewhere in the open interval $0\lt x\lt \infty$.

At the maximum, the *ordinary* derivative $g_b'(x)$ is equal to $0$. Differentiate. We conclude that the maximum is reached at $x=\frac{8}{9b}$, $y=b$.